# error loading jboss-structure.xml from jboss-deployment-structure.xml

Tags: jboss7.x

I just blocked by an error when deploy my project with jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.

```
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Err
or loading jboss-structure.xml from C:\...\myproject.war\WEB-INF\jboss-deploy
ment-structure.xml
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureD
escriptorParser.parse(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:277) [jboss-as-se
rver-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureD
escriptorParser.parse(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:249) [jboss-as-se
rver-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
```

and here is my jboss-deployment-sturcture.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
    <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Please help me if someone know the solution for this error. Tahnks!

Comment: Is there anymore to the exception printed? The XML looks okay.

Answer (score 1):

Check witch version of deployment-structure is available on your JBoss AS.

I had to change version of deployment-structure to 1.1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
    <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```